# What is a good way to save multiple file upload path to database?

Tags: mysql, json

When I save multiple file, I convert them to json type and save them in a file column of Varchar type.

Ex )

| title | content | file |
| --- | --- | --- |
| game | darksoul, M&B, skyrim | ["/upload/test1.jpg","/upload/test2.jpg","/upload/test3.jpg"] |
| book | bookbookbookbookbook | ["/upload/test5.jpg","/upload/test10.jpg"] |

And when loading multiple file, convert the string format back to json and expose it to the screen.

I don't think the method looks very good.

So i will be going to change the file column from varchar to json type so that you don't have to change the type when loading.

However, I think there is a better way to save/load multiple files in DB.

If you know that, please tell me..!

Thank you.

Please let me know if you have any further questions or if my explanation seems strange.
I'll fix it right away.

Comment: Seems like json is well supported in MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html
Why not use it then?

Comment: Why not use a properly normalized database, where you put each individual file in a seperate row of a seperate table?

Comment: Jagrut Sharma, I'm sorry for the late reply. In the question, I will change the column type to json, and I asked you to let me know if there is a better way than this, but I don't think it was delivered properly because I was using a translator. sorry TT

Comment: Nico Haase, I never thought about making a separate table. Thank you so much.

Comment: "To fit 10 images, you must create 10 fields" - no. Just use a normalized database that holds the image  for each row and connect it using the row id. That's how all larger applications do it

Comment: im sorry, I misunderstood the sentence I fixed it right away Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could indeed use the JSON datatype, and that would work okay.

MySQL is a relation database though, which means that data is placed in tables with same properties and then referred to other rows from other tables via identifies (typically primary keys).

So what you could do is make another table called `fileuploads` which will contain columns:

- `id` (primary key, autoincrement)
- `path` (the path to the uploaded file eg "/upload/test1.jpg")
- `foreign_id` (this must contain the id to the table you have shown in the question)

The advantage of doing this is, that you have a strict data structure. If you want to add extra information on the different fileuploads you will be forced to ensure that the information is added to all the existing rows.

If you were to add extra information on the JSON, that is also possible, but you would have a loose datastructure which could cause bugs in your application code (you are not garantied that the "columns" exists).

You furthermore have the option to make use of the standard MySQL features for tables such as indexes, partitions etc.

If I were you I would change the data type to JSON, and then if demands increase in the future I would right away refactor to a separate table.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed reply. You've been a great help.